# Cast int into an array of two bytes

Tags: c++, stdout

I'm a Java programmer and I tried to use two different way of printing bytes into stdout.

```
unsigned char bytes[2];
//...
printf("%x%x", bytes[0], bytes[1]);
std::cout << bytes[0] << bytes[1];
```

But the output of these methods is different. Why? How to make printf output the same as with `std::cout`?

Comment: Your printf call is printing in lower case hexadecimal (the %x) while the cout call is printing the char value.

Comment: What is in `bytes`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `std::cout` they will be printed as characters.

With `printf` integer promotion occurs and they get passed as `int`s, and the `%x` specifier tells `printf` to print an `unsigned int` in hexadecimal format.

You can get `printf` to print a character by using `%c`, or you can get `std::cout` to print it as hex by doing the promotion yourself and setting the `hex` flag:

```
std::printf("%c%c", bytes[0], bytes[1]);
std::cout << std::hex << +bytes[0] << +bytes[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

`%x` outputs a number in a hexadecimal CS, for example, code

```
int x = 80;
printf("%x", x);
```

will print `50`.

To write numbers in decimal form, you have to use `%d`. Also, to print `char` variable in a form of a number, not character, you have to cast it to `int`:

```
unsigned char bytes[2];
//...
printf("%d%d", bytes[0], bytes[1]);
std::cout << (int)bytes[0] << (int)bytes[1];
```

Comment: Different again

Comment: On my computer this code prints identical lines (in fact, they're printed on one line, but anyway they're identical). What is printed in your case?

Comment: @St.Antario: What is in the array?

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent would be :

```
#include <iomanip>  // needed for std::hex

std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned int>(bytes[0]) << static_cast<unsigned int>(bytes[1]);
```

Two differences :

- your `printf` with `%x` prints in hexadecimal - for C++ streams, there's [`std::hex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) for that
- your `printf` takes `int` values (for `%x`), but C++ streams don't have an [`operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) that prints a `unsigned char` as an integer value (instead it'll be printed as a character), so you need to cast the `unsigned char` to an integer type first (eg. `unsigned int` as in the code above)